# Can you get "Documenttitle from a user control?

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp

I have created a user control with navigation buttons and textbox at top and a webview at bottom and the user control is called "browser". In my MainPage.xaml I have a Pivot and I load "browser like this ...

`<PivotItem>
   <local:Browser/>
</PivotItem>`

and this all works! On my Pivot I have add and remove buttons to create new PivotItems with "browser" in them and that all works! What I cant figure out is how do I get the WebView.DocumetTitle from the WebView in "browser" control so I can put it in the PivotItem.Header when I create a new PivotItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a dependency property and bind the PivotItem's header to it. Then you could register `NavigationCompleted` event for your WebView. When this event is fired, you could get current document page's title and assign this value to the dependency property. Then, the PivotItem's header will be updated.

I've made a simple code sample for your reference:

```xml
<UserControl
x:Class="App1.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="txbUri" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
    <Button Content="Go" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <WebView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="webview" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" NavigationCompleted="WebView_NavigationCompleted"></WebView>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("default"));

    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void WebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.Title = sender.DocumentTitle;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(txbUri.Text.Trim());
            webview.Navigate(uri);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem Header="{Binding ElementName=uc,Path=Title}">
        <local:MyUserControl1 x:Name="uc"></local:MyUserControl1>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try when I get home from work! I hope it works I have been beating my brains out trying to figure it out! I like trying to figure it out before asking for help!